# USB 1-5 string descriptor 0 read error: -22

Tags: boot, usb

I have installed ubuntu 15.04 on my Acer aspire V15 and everytime I boot my system up I get the error mentioned above for about 10-20 seconds then another black screen with some writing then it boots up normally. I have search the internets for a solution but have not found anything even the least bit helpful.

When I run the command `dmesg | grep -i usb` I get this with the error inside

```
[    1.046362] ACPI: bus type USB registered
[    1.046374] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    1.046381] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    1.046395] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.375556] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 1
[    1.375673] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.375674] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.375675] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.375676] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 3.19.0-18-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.375677] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.375750] hub 1-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.377107] xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 2
[    1.377125] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003
[    1.377126] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.377127] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.377128] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 3.19.0-18-generic xhci-hcd
[    1.377129] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    1.377196] hub 2-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.377693] ehci_hcd: USB 2.0 'Enhanced' Host Controller (EHCI) Driver
[    1.377767] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
[    1.393590] ehci-pci 0000:00:1d.0: USB 2.0 started, EHCI 1.00
[    1.393615] usb usb3: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002
[    1.393617] usb usb3: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.393618] usb usb3: Product: EHCI Host Controller
[    1.393619] usb usb3: Manufacturer: Linux 3.19.0-18-generic ehci_hcd
[    1.393620] usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:1d.0
[    1.393702] hub 3-0:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.393794] ohci_hcd: USB 1.1 'Open' Host Controller (OHCI) Driver
[    1.393811] uhci_hcd: USB Universal Host Controller Interface driver
[    1.685839] usb 1-3: new full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.705842] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using ehci-pci
[    1.816647] usb 1-3: New USB device found, idVendor=046d, idProduct=c52b
[    1.816662] usb 1-3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    1.816664] usb 1-3: Product: USB Receiver
[    1.816665] usb 1-3: Manufacturer: Logitech
[    1.824486] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    1.824488] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    1.826626] logitech-djreceiver 0003:046D:C52B.0003: hiddev0,hidraw0: USB HID v1.11 Device [Logitech USB Receiver] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3/input2
[    1.838305] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=8087, idProduct=8000
[    1.838308] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    1.838570] hub 3-1:1.0: USB hub found
[    1.981990] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.111757] usb 1-5: string descriptor 0 read error: -22
[    2.111797] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0489, idProduct=e04e
[    2.111798] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.278195] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[    2.407801] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=04f3, idProduct=0389
[    2.407816] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=4, Product=14, SerialNumber=0
[    2.407818] usb 1-6: Product: Touchscreen
[    2.407819] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: ELAN
[    2.407917] usb 1-6: ep 0x2 - rounding interval to 64 microframes, ep desc says 80 microframes
[    2.578380] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 5 using xhci_hcd
[    2.771317] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=04f2, idProduct=b469
[    2.771320] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.771321] usb 1-7: Product: HD WebCam
[    2.771322] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: Chicony Electronics Co.,Ltd.
[   15.381758] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[   15.487852] input: Logitech M215 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:1020.0004/input/input7
[   15.487962] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:1020.0004: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.11 Mouse [Logitech M215] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3:1
[   15.489577] input: ELAN Touchscreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/0003:04F3:0389.0006/input/input8
[   15.489662] hid-multitouch 0003:04F3:0389.0006: input,hiddev0,hidraw2: USB HID v1.10 Device [ELAN Touchscreen] on usb-0000:00:14.0-6/input0
[   15.491892] input: Logitech K360 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-3/1-3:1.2/0003:046D:C52B.0003/0003:046D:4004.0005/input/input10
[   15.491954] logitech-hidpp-device 0003:046D:4004.0005: input,hidraw3: USB HID v1.11 Keyboard [Logitech K360] on usb-0000:00:14.0-3:2
[   15.932841] usbcore: registered new interface driver ath3k
[   15.932886] usb 1-5: USB disconnect, device number 3
[   16.202714] usb 1-5: new full-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
[   16.408156] usb 1-5: string descriptor 0 read error: -22
[   16.408180] usb 1-5: New USB device found, idVendor=0489, idProduct=e04e
[   16.408182] usb 1-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[   16.740426] input: HD WebCam as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-7/1-7:1.0/input/input16
[   16.740487] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
[   16.740488] USB Video Class driver (1.1.1)
sean@Keane710-Acer:~$
```

hoping this will help someone solve this problem for me and others...
Thanks!!!!